# how to add a trailing zeroes to multiple parts of a string

Tags: r

I have the following data

v1
19956673-1
20043747-23
20056956-1
36628-2
45820-4
478
115

I need to add trailing zeroes to the both sting fields (before and after the dash) so the desired output (v2) has 8 digits before the dash and 2 digits after. Also, data with no dash can be passed as is.

```
v1             v2
19956673-1    19956673-01
20043747-23   20043747-23
20056956-1    20056956-01
36628-2       00036628-02
45820-4       00045820-04
478           478
115           115
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option to extract the part after the `-`, then use `sprintf`

```
 i1 <- grep('-', df1$v1)
 df1$v2 <- df1$v1
 df1$v2[i1] <- sprintf('%s-%02d', sub('-.*', '', df1$v1[i1]), 
               as.numeric(sub('.*-', '', df1$v1[i1])))
```

-output

```
df1
#           v1          v2
#1  19956673-1 19956673-01
#2 20043747-23 20043747-23
#3  20056956-1 20056956-01
#4     36628-2    36628-02
#5     45820-4    45820-04
#6         478         478
#7         115         115
```

---

Or another option is regex based on capturing as a group i.e. match the digits (`\\d+`) from the start (`^`) of the string, capture as a group (`(...)`), followed by a `-`, then capture the single digit (`\\d`) at the end (`$`), replace with the backreference of the captured groups and insert 0 before the second backreference

```
df1$v2 <- sub('^(\\d+)-(\\d)$', '\\1-0\\2', df1$v1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("19956673-1", "20043747-23", "20056956-1", 
"36628-2", "45820-4", "478", "115")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), 
   class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: i just though on a constrain i have (i already edited the question): some data has no dashes and i will need to pass them as is.

Comment: @AndresMora in my second solution, it works even without any change.  For the first one, I modified

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `sub` and positive lookbehind:

```
v2 <- sub("(?<=-)(\\d)$", "0\\1", v1, perl = TRUE)
```

Result:

```
v2
[1] "19956673-01" "20043747-23" "20056956-01" "36628-02"    "45820-04"
```

How this works:

- `(?<=-)`: positive lookbehind: "if you see a `-` on the left ...
- `(\\d)$`: ... then *remember* (`\\1`) the single digit (`(\\d)`) right at the end of the string (`$`) and add a `0` to the left of it"

Data:

```
v1 <- c("19956673-1", "20043747-23", "20056956-1", "36628-2", "45820-4")
```